# I want to show addition of two number without using any button

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

I have two input boxes with id `no1` and `no2`. I have to put two integer values on both inputs and show their sum without using any button. My code works, but it shows only the individual values, not the calculated sum.

How can I show my addition value In real time when user is just typing?

```js
var c;
var a = document.getElementById("no1");
var b = document.getElementById("no2");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var m = document.getElementById("message");

a.onfocus = function() {
  m.style.display = "block";
}

a.onblur = function() {
  m.style.display = "none";
}

a.onkeyup = function() {
  var c;
  if (isNaN(a.value) == false) {
    c = a.value + b.value;
    m.innerHTML = c;
  } else {

    m.innerHTML = "<font color='red' size='45px'><strong>Must containe number only</strong></font>";
  }
}
b.onfocus = function() {
  m.style.display = "block";
}
b.onblur = function() {
  m.style.display = "none";
}
b.onkeyup = function() {

  if (isNaN(b.value) == false) {
    c = a.value + b.value;
    m.innerHTML = c;
  } else {

    m.innerHTML = "<font color='red' size='45px'><strong>Must containe number only</strong></font>";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="no1" name="no1" />
  <input type="text" id="no2" name="no2" />
  <button onclick="myFun()">Press Me</button>
</div>

<center>
  <font color="blue" size="45px" id="message"></font>
</center>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var c; 
var a = document.getElementById("no1"); 
var b = document.getElementById("no2"); 
var number = document.getElementById("number"); 
var m = document.getElementById("message"); 
a.onfocus = function() { 
m.style.display = "block"; } 
a.onblur = function() { 
m.style.display = "none"; } 
a.onkeyup = function() { 
var c;
if (isNaN(a.value) == false) { 
c = Number(a.value) + Number(b.value); 
m.innerHTML = c; 
}
else { 
m.innerHTML = "<font color='red' size='45px'><strong>Must containe number only</strong></font>";
}
}
b.onfocus = function() { 
m.style.display = "block"; } 
b.onblur = function() { 
m.style.display = "none"; } 
b.onkeyup = function() { 

if (isNaN(b.value) == false) { 
c = Number(a.value) + Number(b.value); 
m.innerHTML = c;
} 
else { 
m.innerHTML = "<font color='red' size='45px'><strong>Must containe number only</strong></font>"; 
}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Input values are strings, which are concatenated by the `+` sign.
In order to add them together, use [`parseInt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to convert to an integer.

I've also included a way to handle non-numeric values:

```
c = (parseInt(a.value)||0) + (parseInt(b.value)||0);
```

Also, the [`<font>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/font) and [`<center>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center) tags are obsolete.
I suggest using CSS instead.

Example below:

```js
var c;
var a = document.getElementById("no1");
var b = document.getElementById("no2");
var number = document.getElementById("number");
var m = document.getElementById("message");

a.onfocus = function() {
  m.style.display = "block";
}

a.onblur = function() {
  m.style.display = "none";
}

a.onkeyup = function() {
  var c;
  if (isNaN(a.value) == false) {
    c = (parseInt(a.value) || 0) + (parseInt(b.value) || 0);
    m.innerHTML = c;
  } else {
    m.innerHTML = "Must contain number only";
  }
}
b.onfocus = function() {
  m.style.display = "block";
}
b.onblur = function() {
  m.style.display = "none";
}
b.onkeyup = function() {

  if (isNaN(b.value) == false) {
    c = (parseInt(a.value) || 0) + (parseInt(b.value) || 0);
    m.innerHTML = c;
  } else {
    m.innerHTML = "Must contain number only";
  }
}
```

```css
#message {
  color: blue;
  font-size: 45px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <input type="text" id="no1" name="no1">
  <input type="text" id="no2" name="no2">
</div>

<div id="message"></div>
```

Comment: This only needs a small improvement that guards against instances where the other input is blank. Currently it returns NaN if you're typing in a and b is blank because you're trying to parse an empty string to an integer.

Comment: @dukedevil294 Agreed, thank you.

Comment: Thanks i it work well

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code is that when you are doing `a.value + b.value` it is actually not doing sum but is concating two string as `a.value is string not number`. so you have to convert string to number(by using `parseInt` or `parseFloat`). 
You can remove redundant code by doing following things.

```js
var c;
var a = document.getElementById("no1");
var b = document.getElementById("no2");
var m = document.getElementById("message");

var x=document.querySelectorAll("input");
for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].addEventListener('focus', function() {
        m.style.display = "block";
    });
    x[i].addEventListener('keyup', function() {
        var c;
        if (isNaN(a.value) == false) {
          c = parseInt(a.value || 0) + parseInt(b.value || 0);
          m.innerHTML = c;
        } else {

          m.innerHTML = "<font color='red' size='45px'><strong>Must containe                    number only</strong></font>";
        }
    });
    x[i].addEventListener('blur', function() {
        m.style.display = "none";
    });
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>


  <div class="container">

    <input type="text" id="no1" name="no1" />
    <input type="text" id="no2" name="no2" />
    <button onclick="myFun()">Press Me</button>

  </div>
  <center>
    <font color="blue" size="45px" id="message"></font>
  </center>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Redundant code wasn't the question. What was the problem and what did you do to solve it?

Comment: I agree but if there is better solution then why not use it.

Comment: I agree, you made the code more efficient. But your code also solves the OP's issue and it would improve your answer to explain how you did that.

Comment: I agree, and applied changes @showdev thanks for pointing out that.

Answer (score 1):

Form controls like `<input>` store value as a string. Use the [**`.valueAsNumber`**](https://webplatform.github.io/docs/dom/HTMLInputElement/valueAsNumber/) property so you don't need to convert any string values to numbers afterwards with `parseInt()`, `parseFloat()`, `Number()`, etc.

<del>inputObj1.value + inputObj2.value</del>

inputObj1.**valueAsNumber** + inputObj2.**valueAsNumber**

The following demo has 2 examples. The first example uses **[HTMLFormControlsCollection API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormControlsCollection)** and **[`.addEventListener()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)**. The second example uses an **[onevent attribute event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers)**.

Both examples need to use a `<form>` tag. and I replaced the `<center>` and `<font>` tags (they are HTML4 not HTML5) with an [`<output>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/output) tag. I also changed the `<input>` `type` to `number`.

Both examples register the `input` event to the `<form>` tag. Within the `eventListener` there's a condition that will only process user input from `<input type='number'>` tags. The onevent attribute handler on the second example only needs a function expression. The `input` event will fire as soon as the user enters text.

### Demo

```js
var container1 = document.forms.container1;

var con1 = container1.elements;

container1.addEventListener('input', function(e) {
  if (e.target.type === 'number') {
    con1.message1.value = con1.no1.valueAsNumber + con1.no2.valueAsNumber;
  }
}, false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>


  <form id="container1">

    <input type="number" id="no1" name="no1">
    <input type="number" id="no2" name="no2">



    <output id="message1" style='color:blue; font-size:45px; text-align:center; display:block;'></output>

  </form>



  <form id="container2" oninput='message2.value = no3.valueAsNumber + no4.valueAsNumber'>

    <input type="number" id="no3" name="no3">
    <input type="number" id="no4" name="no4">



    <output id="message2" style='color:blue; font-size:45px; text-align:center; display:block;'></output>

  </form>


</body>

</html>
```